# Getting character attributes

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

Using WinAPI to get the attribute of a character located in y line and x column of the screen console.
This is what I am trying to do after a call to  `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &nativeData);` where the console cursor is set to the specified location. This won't work. It will return the last used attribute change instead.

How do I obtain the attributes used on all the characters on their locations?

---

**EDIT:**
The code I used to test `ReadConsoleOutput()` : http://hastebin.com/atohetisin.pl
It throws garbage values.

Comment: Did you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685032(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter perhaps yes, but I am working on a HUGE project that will contribute the entire environment of console-application programmers and I can't waste time on doing it wrong (I don't like the way windows manage things). The best scenerio will be someone saying that this is the function I need and provide me with an example of how to use it with hopefully less code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems off the top of my head:

- No error checking.  You must check the return value for ReadConsoleOutput and other functions, as documented.  If the function fails, you must call GetLastError() to get the error code.  If you don't check for errors, you're flying blind.
- You don't allocate a buffer to receive the data in.  (Granted, the documentation confusingly implies that it allocates the buffer for you, but that's obviously wrong since there's no way for it to return a pointer to it.  Also, the sample code clearly shows that you have to allocate the buffer yourself.  I've added a note.)
- It looks as if you had intended to read the characters you had written, but you are writing to (10,5) and reading from (0,0).
- You're passing `newpos`, which is set to (10,5), as `dwBufferCoord` when you call ReadConsoleOutput, but you specified a buffer size of (2,1).  It doesn't make sense for the target coordinates to be outside the buffer.

Taking those last two points together I think perhaps you have `dwBufferCoord` and `lpReadRegion` confused, though I'm not sure what you meant the coordinates (200,50) to do.

- You're interpreting `CHAR_INFO` as an integer in the final `printf` statement.  The first element of `CHAR_INFO` is the character itself, not the attribute.  You probably wanted to say `chiBuffer[0].Attributes` rather than just `chiBuffer[0]`.  (Of course, this is moot at the moment, since `chiBuffer` points to a random memory address.)

If you do want to retrieve the character, you'll first need to work out whether the console is in Unicode or ASCII mode, and retrieve UnicodeChar or AsciiChar accordingly.